# Calling extension method's overload with derived type

Tags: c#, casting, extension-methods

Simplified, i have these 2 `Extension` method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetString(this Exception e)
    {
        return "Standard!!!";
    }
    public static string GetString(this TimeoutException e)
    {
        return "TimeOut!!!";
    }
}
```

And here is where i use them:

```
try
{
    throw new TimeoutException();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Type t = e.GetType(); //At debugging this a TimeoutException
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetString()); //Prints: Standard
}
```

I have more `GetString()` extensions.

My `try{...}catch{...}` is getting large and basically i search for ways to shorten it down to 1 catch that calls the extension based on the type of the exception.

**Is there a way to call the right extension method at runtime?**

Comment: Do you need to call it as an extension method? `dynamic` can help here, but it does not support extension methods.

Comment: use multiple catch blocks for each type of exception?, with `catch (Exception e)` being the last of the catch blocks ofcourse.

Comment: i.e., `Console.WriteLine(Extensions.GetString((dynamic) e));`

Comment: Extensions seem the wrong tool here. You will need a `switch`, with or without the fancy new pattern matching.

Comment: @bommelding you're probably right... I just hoped to avoid a switch.

Comment: What do you expect from TimeoutException.GetString() to be really printed ? "TimeOut!!!" or something else ? Is TimeoutException a class of yours ? As bommelding said, extensions methods seem to be the wrong tool here.

Comment: @Spotted `GetString` seems to be a simplification of some error handling method that is called depending on the type of exception.

Comment: Do all the `GetString()` share common behavior ?

Comment: they share signature with only different argument type of the Exception. 
however they differ in the work done before returning a formatted string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Yacoub Massad suggests you can use `dynamic`, because with `dynamic` method overload resolution is deferred at runtime through late binding.:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetString<T>(this T e) where T : Exception
    {
        // dynamic method overload resolution is deferred at runtime through late binding.
        return GetStringCore((dynamic)e);
    }

    static string GetStringCore(Exception e)
    {
        return "Standard!!!";
    }

    static string GetStringCore(TimeoutException e)
    {
        return "TimeOut!!!";
    }

    static string GetStringCore(InvalidOperationException e)
    {
        return "Invalid!!!";
    }
}
```

This should make the trick.

Comment: You should add that to your answer so we can delete these 2 comments :-)

Comment: I don't think you need the `GetString` method to be generic. It can take `Exception`.

Comment: But you need to care of the conflicting method names if you make it non-generic.

Comment: @YacoubMassad you're but i like this better since i don't need to come up with 2 method names.

Comment: The only problem I can see here is that everyone interacting with this code has to understand `(dynamic)e`. I would put a nice, lengthy comment to explain what this code actually does.

Comment: @FCin that is EXACTLY why i'm not marking this as an answer yet :-)

Comment: What's the behavior if one does `new ArgumentException().GetString()` ? (assuming the corresponding static method doesn't exist)

Comment: @Spotted: you'll get a nice infinite loop as the best overloaded match will be the generic method itself. So yes, giving the private methods a distinct name is highly recommended.

Comment: @Mike: If you were really married to the name `GetString`, you could use an inner class, with the same net effect of making the methods exist in a different scope altogether. I think there's nothing wrong and everything right with naming the methods in such a way that there's obviously no chance of an infinite loop ever occurring. `dynamic` is sufficiently magical as it is without adding in hacks.

Comment: @JeroenMostert not at all hooked on the `GetString` my actual code return `HttpResonseMessage`. I just do alot of stuff that wasn't related to the question... My concern is that i throw an `exception` that i have not written an `extension` for

Comment: @Mike: no properly written code throws a raw `Exception`, so you could simply have `static string GetStringCore(Exception e) => throw new NotImplementedException($"Hey Mike, write something for {e.GetType()}, will ya?");`. Leaving it out altogether is also an option, but you'll get a far less intuitive `RuntimeBinderException`. (There is no way to get a proper error at *compile time* as long as you're working through the base `Exception` type, since you are relying on identifying the runtime type on way or another.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert where would this get called? as a try catch in the generic `GetString`?

Comment: @Mike: it gets called whenever `GetString` tries to find the proper overload for `GetStringCore`. If there is no overload that takes a `FooException`, the best matching overload is the one matching `Exception`. `e.GetString()` would always invoke the generic method in this setup, regardless of the actual type of `e`, so you don't need to adjust your `try`/`catch` handlers. Within `GetString`, there is no need to `try`/`catch` -- how would you even handle the exception `GetStringCore(Exception)` produces in a way that it can't do itself?

Answer (score -1):

Extension methods are the wrong tool here.

I would foster the use of polymorphism to solve your problem:

```
public abstract class BaseException : Exception
{
    public abstract string GetString();
}

public sealed class TimeoutException : BaseException
{
    public override string GetString() => "TimeOut!!!";
}

public sealed class MyException : BaseException
{
    public override string GetString() => "Standard!!!";
}
```

Usage

```
try
{
    throw new TimeoutException(); //or whatever BaseException's children
}
catch (BaseException e)
{
    //here I'm assuming you know that you are swallowing the exception (which may be an anti-pattern)
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetString());
}
```

## Edit

It looks like you have not the full control over which and when exceptions are thrown. Another possibility would be to add 1 catch clause for each behavior (rather than for each exception type) and get rid of `GetString()`:

```
try
{
    throw new TimeoutException();
}
catch (Exception e) when (e is ArgumentNullException || e is FormatException)
{
    //do something
}
catch (Exception e) when (e is TimeoutException)
{
    //do something
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException($"Hey Mike, write something for {e.GetType()}, will ya?"); //idea from Jeroen
}
```

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me how you would use this for non-custom exceptions like `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: @Spotted You cannot override already existing exceptions, such as `ArgumentException`...

Comment: Yes, classic OO... But also generating a whole layer of new classes. And your application code never throws `TimeoutException` , the library does. How would you handle that?

Comment: @Spotted reading your edit this is pretty much same as the answer delivered by Amit:
Great. I also have SqlException, NullReferenceException, XmlException and 9-10 different custom exceptions, probably more... Can you see where this answer becomes a problem? :-)

Comment: @Mike indeed with more custom exceptions the code would become rather cumbersome. I fear I have no better solution to give except the one that you wrap exceptions that are out of your control into exceptions that you control as soon as they are raised.